# Pusher Heroku Add-on error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, pusher

so I'm using the Pusher Heroku Add-on for my application. The application has live notifications, so when a user receives a message he will see a pop up notification saying "new message". However, In production I am getting the below error:

```
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/b1cc5d4f400faddcb40b?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.1.6&flash=false.
Reload the page to get source for: http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js
```

And here's the Pusher controller:

```
class PusherController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery :except => :auth # stop rails CSRF protection for this action

  def auth
    Pusher.app_id = ENV['PUSHER_APP_ID']
    Pusher.key = ENV['PUSHER_KEY']
    Pusher.secret = ENV['PUSHER_SECRET']



    if current_user && params[:channel_name] == "private-user-#{current_user.id}"
      response = Pusher[params[:channel_name]].authenticate(params[:socket_id])
      render :json => response
    else
      render :text => "Not authorized", :status => '403'
    end
  end
end
```

And I'm using the [figaro gem](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to push the keys to heroku.

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

**JS**

That looks like a problem with Javascript, rather than Rails

We've got pusher working very well with one of our production apps, and it works by firstly having the [`pusher` gem](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem) installed, allowing you to call the `pusher` JS files from your layout:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js" %>
```

**Rails**

You may also wish to put the pusher initialization code into an initializer:

```
#config/initializers/pusher.rb
Pusher.url = ENV["PUSHER_URL"]

Pusher.app_id = ENV["PUSHER_APP_ID"]
Pusher.key = ENV["PUSHER_KEY"]
Pusher.secret = ENV["PUSHER_SECRET"]
```

This will ensure app-wide connectivity, rather than controller-specific (allowing for greater flexibility)

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I do have that code in my initializers/pusher.rb and it still isn't connecting properly. Not quite sure what the problem is here.

Comment: Perhaps your firewall is blocking? Also, do you have the JS in your layout?

Comment: Yes, this line is in the application.html.erb <%= javascript_include_tag "http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js" %>. Let me try in another browser, good point.

Comment: Weird, but good call - I'm not getting the JS error on Chrome but only on Firefox. Why might that be?

Answer (score 0):

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://ws.pusherapp.com/app/b1cc5d4f400faddcb40b?protocol=7&client=js&version=2.1.6&flash=false.
>   Reload the page to get source for: http://js.pusher.com/2.1/pusher.min.js

This doesn't necessarily mean anything is wrong. it just means that an unsecured WebSocket connection couldn't be established. Pusher's [fallback strategy](http://pusher.com/docs/fallbacks) should result in a successful connection being established via either HTTP fallback (HTTP or HTTPS) or via WSS (a secure WebSocket connection).

Failed connection attempts are logged as console errors. There's nothing that can be done about that.

To test this you can bind to [connection events](http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_connect#binding-to-events) and ensure that you are indeed connecting. The pusher-js [JavaScript logging](http://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging) will also help determine what's happening.

You can also try http://test.pusher.com/

Comment: Got it, it seems like I am only getting this error in Firefox and not in Chrome. What might I do to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Is it still connecting in Firefox? See my answer for details on deyermongvifbit is. You can't stop the error message being logged as it's a network level browser message.